# Don't include answers in question lists by default

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Right now, question list API queries (such as `/questions`, `/questions/unanswered`, `/user/{id}/questions` and so on) also return at most 30 answers (apparently) for each question. While this might be useful under certain conditions, I think in most cases it's not. Most applications will only want to display a list of questions without any answer. **Having** to download 30- answers (well, sans their body) for each question seems like a waste of bandwidth and stackexchange computing power, especially when fetching answer-heavy question lists (such as [/questions?sort=votes](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?sort=votes) -- that query would be greatly reduced if there were no answers included).

This especially affects mobile devices where bandwidth is precious and processing power is both sparse and battery-consuming.

In conclusion, I think the answers should be taken away from question lists (maybe a parameter to bring them back if they're really needed). Or, at the very least, include a parameter that specifies no answers should be included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask and ye shall receive<sup>*</sup>.

[Documentation.](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions)

<sub>*Limitted time offer.</sub>

Comment: And what is the default? If false it will break current applications for sure.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Kevin! @SztupY: yes, the default is false. You can run a simple query and see for yourself.

Comment: @Kevin: it doesn't seem like it's working. `answers=true` does not return answers: http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?pagesize=2&type=jsontext&sort=votes&answers=true (I have no problem with this as I'm not using it anyway, but for other people that might use it)

Comment: @Kevin: `/answers/{id}` and `/users/{id}/answers` now document this `answers` parameter, which doesn't make much sense to me. It doesn't seem to do anything though.

Comment: @Kevin: I think it would make a little more sense to make the answers parameter a number, so that you can specify how many answers per question should be returned. The default being 0.

Answer (score 0):

Option like `answers=true/false` would be great. Because including answers save API daily rate-limit, on other side. So both can be happier adding an option `answers=true/false`, instead of just dropping it.