# The /search route is ignoring the answers parameter.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, search

The answers parameter was recently added to most of the requests that return a list of questions.  See: [Don’t include answers in question lists by default](https://stackapps.com/questions/613/dont-include-answers-in-question-lists-by-default)

It looks like the [/search](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=search) request got left out.  It appears to never return answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [by-design].

`/search` is already pretty resource intensive, and not returning answers is a conscious effort to reduce its runtime.

The `answers` parameter does not appear in the [documentation for `/search`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=search) accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

[The `/search/excerpts` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) looks to be about as good as `/search` and it *does* return both questions and answers, and it does have an `answers` parameter.

This route is "★ All new! For version 2.2! ★"