# How to search answers like is:answer

Tags: support, feature-request, api-v2.2, search, answers

How can I use the API to search for answers containing particular text or with particular properties? For example, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+foo) allows me to search for `is:answer foo`, that is, answers containing `foo`. Can I do this with the current API?

Note: I have already searched the documentation, but didn't find anything like this.

Comment: Note that the `/search` paths are the only ones that allow much text searching and [they omit answers by design](http://stackapps.com/a/655/7653).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forget when, but sometime in the last couple of years, [the `/search/excerpts` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) started allowing `is:answer` in the `q` parameter.

For example:
          [/2.2/search/excerpts?&q=Hear! is:answer&site=stackapps](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=Hear!%20is%3Aanswer&filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true)

-- which returns Stack Apps answers with the text "Hear!" in the body.

<sub>(Pretty sure I tested this in early 2014, and it didn't work then. But, other parts of the API have stealthily changed.)</sub>