# How do I search answer bodies for Markdown links?

Tags: support, api, search, answers

The `/search/excerpt` query [enables searching answers for specific text](https://stackapps.com/questions/4583/how-to-search-answers-like-isanswer/7633#7633), but searching for Markdown links returns results that don't seem to match the query at all. For instance, the following [query value](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=%22%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fvuejs.org%2Fv2%22%20is%3Aanswer&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) attempts to search answers with links that start with `https://vuejs.org/v2` (by looking for the tail end of such a Markdown link):

```
"](https://vuejs.org/v2" is:answer
```

But it returns the following irrelevant posts (subset):

- [Django : customizing FileField's current file in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72416598)
- [How to setup grid layout with mapped react bootstrap cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56249782)
- [Is there any way to set auto increment sequence field in nest js and mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72989709)

It's possible that my query is wrong (perhaps escape characters are needed). What query should I use to enable this search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search methods work on the HTML version of the post, so searching for Markdown won't work. You can either use this parameter

> `url` - a url which must be contained in a post, may include a wildcard.

leading to [this API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=is%3Aanswer&url=*%2F%2Fvuejs.org%2Fv2*&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), or mimic a site search (I would search for [`url:"vuejs.org/v2" is:answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22vuejs.org%2Fv2%22+is%3Aanswer&searchOn=1)) and that leads to [this API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=url%3A%22vuejs.org%2Fv2%22%20is%3Aanswer&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: Just noticed the "[repairing broken images or links](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1581086/broken-links-images-fixed)"  in your profile. That's exactly what I'm doing right now: fixing up old URLs (https://vuejs.org/v2) to point to the new one (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2). I'm currently using a script to update posts from a search one a a time (super slow), but I didn't realize SQL could do this for me in one step. Can you recommend a SQL script for me?

Comment: If it's a simple find & replace, [staff has a tool which can do that easily without bumping questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232). I'd recommend to post on Meta Stack Overflow about this. My script(s) can help when it's more difficult.

Comment: Ah, of course. I should've thought of asking staff before writing my own script! ‍♂️