# Search by team API - want to have same query results in StackOverflow.com site

Tags: support, search, api-v2.3, stack-overflow-for-teams

I just want to have same query result like stackoverflow.com did. I read this post:[Searching on Stack Overflow and using the API give different results?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4816/searching-on-stack-overflow-and-using-the-api-give-different-results).

looks like /search/excerpts is the right choice: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=raml%20rest&filter=!m6Wy7AFuaogF.dVbTekNC-J-hhkc1uWKI08gO_52dnbUs-bpQ7Fj).qM&site=stackoverflow&run=true

While the question is: there are many parameters, could you give an example payload which will return same query results like stackoverflow.com site did?

I'm using java, is there official java stackoverflow client which I can use?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "official" Java client. I assume Java comes with an [HTTP client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) in its standard library. That one should do the trick.

The minimal example you need is this URL (click it!):

> [`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/excerpts?q=raml rest&site=stackoverflow`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/excerpts?q=raml%20rest&site=stackoverflow)

An HTTP Get will work, no need to Post.

So that URL has the following parameters in its [query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search):

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| q | what you want to search for |
| site | the site to perform the API call on |

The returned JSON payload is an JSON Object with an `items` array that holds the [`search_excerpt`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/search-excerpt) objects.

I do advice to use an extra parameter called `filter` with this value `!nKzQUR693x`. It will return in the wrapper object the number of total hits. You get at most 100 hits (set the `pagesize`, default is 15!) in one go so you have to make that call a couple of times if there are more then 100 results. Supplying the `page` parameter will allow you to fetch subsequent pages of the total result.

Combining all that gives this URL

> [`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/excerpts?q=raml%20rest&site=stackoverflow&filter=!nKzQUR693x&page=5`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/excerpts?q=raml%20rest&site=stackoverflow&filter=!nKzQUR693x&page=5)

For the record: The API search reports that it found a total of 240 excerpts, which is [the same number found on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=raml+rest) today.

For accessing the same endpoint in an Stack Overflow for Teams team you need to follow the steps mentioned in [Stack Overflow for Teams API](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385859-stack-overflow-for-teams-api) and first register an App: [I only need a key, what do I do?](https://stackapps.com/questions/8971/i-only-need-a-key-what-do-i-do) it is important to enter in the `OAuth domain` the url `stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`.

Once you have registered you app, you can authenticate by completing this URL and paste it in a browser:

> `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=<client_id>&scope=no_expiry access_team|stackoverflow.com/c/<team name>&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`

Notice the `<client_id>` and `<team name>` bits that needs to be replaced (including the < and > ) by values you only can know. Client_Id is found on your App registration page.

When the URL did its thing and you granted access the response in the url contains your `access_token`.

Now you have all the parameters you need to make the call for a Team:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| q | what you want to search for |
| site | the site to perform the API call on |
| key | the key as found on your App registration page |
| team | stackoverflow.com/c/<your team name> |

In the HTTP Headers you send this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| X-API-Access-Token | The access_token you got when you authenticated your App |

That completes the extra bits you need for calling that search/excerpts endpoint for a Team instead of a public SE site.

To be complete, here is a JavaScript Example:

```js
var url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/excerpts?q=raml%20rest&site=stackoverflow&filter=!nKzQUR693x';

var inTeams = true;

var fetchinit = {} // for headers

if (inTeams) {
  var yourTeam = '<team name here>' 
  var yourAccessToken = '<your access token>';
  var yourKey = '<your key here>';

  url = url + '&key=' + yourKey
  url = url + '&team=stackoverflow.com/c/' + yourTeam;
  
  fetchinit.headers = {'X-API-Access-Token' : yourAccessToken }
}


function build(i) {
  console.log(i.title);
}

fetch(url, fetchinit)
  .then((resp)=> resp.json())
  .then((json) => json.items)
  .then((items) => items.forEach(build));
```