# OBSOLETE - Stack Addict: Always-on StackExchange question viewer (Chrome Extension)

Tags: app, obsolete, chrome-extensions, soapi.js

Stack Addict is a question-list widget accessible at any time, from any page you're on. Pressing a simple keyboard-shortcut brings up the question viewer, from which you can search, sort, and filter questions for your favorite StackExchange site. With Stack Addict, you can satisfy your craving for answering questions whenever you're online.

---

### Screenshots

Full page with question viewer and StackTack
[image: Full page with question viewer and StackTack]

Hover over question to preview
[image: Hover over question to preview]

Filter by various criteria
[image: Filter by various criteria]

---

### Features

- Support for 80+ sites on the StackExchange network
- Automatically refreshes every 15-60 seconds
- Filter by activity, votes, featured, unanswered, and tags
- Tooltip preview for questions on hover
- See full question and answers with the embedded StackTack viewer
- Customizable keyboard shortcut and mouse behavior

---

### Download

[Free from Google Chrome Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ohogkmbdkhpnigpjhhgaloemmhbhddnj) (*editor note: link is 404*)

---

### Contact

Stack Addict was created by [Rui J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353020/rui-j) of [roowii.net](http://roowii.net). If you'd like to learn more about Stack Addict or to collaborate on new features, ping him with rjiang.bb[at]gmail.com

---

### Libraries

Stack Addict owes a lot to the libraries it was built on:

- [Soapi.js](https://stackapps.com/questions/494/soapi-js-fluent-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-api) - Javascript library for the Stack API (modified for the 1.1 API)
- [StackTack](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere) - Modal question/answer viewer for StackOverflow (modified to support more sites)
- [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) - jQuery tooltips
- [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) - jQuery fuzzy-time plugin
- [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) - Douglas Crockford's JSON parser/serializer
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) - Animations and widgets for jQuery
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - Of course