# Has anyone made a wordpress plugin for stack api?

Tags: discussion, php

Just wondering if as it would be nice to put a widget on a wordpress post that allows people to add new questions and answer them right there in the blog.

Comment: Well, unfortunately you're not going to find any plugins that allow answering directly in the blog due to the API being read-only at the moment. [StackTack](http://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere) may be what you're looking for.