# Stack Tunnel - WebGL Visualization for Stack Exchange

Tags: app, api, api-v2, javascript, open-source

## [Stack Tunnel](http://crashthatch.com/stacktunnel/)

### Screenshots

[image: Stack Tunnel]
[image]
[image: Question Details]
[image]

### About

StackTunnel is a WebGL visualization which displays the latest questions from any Stack Exchange site interactively within your web browser. You can click on the questions to see the full question & answers. If you have a WebGL enabled browser (tested in latest Chrome and Firefox), visit the links below to see it in action.

Stack Tunnel was built in under a week mainly to give me a chance to experiment with WebGL and the new Stack Exchange 2.0 API. It was finished off in somewhat of a hurry to meet the  deadline for the [competition](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-public-beta/).

### Live Demo

Stack Overflow: http://crashthatch.com/stacktunnel/

ServerFault: http://crashthatch.com/stacktunnel/#serverfault

Gaming: http://crashthatch.com/stacktunnel/#gaming

etc. (Add any api_site_parameter to the #item at the end of the URL to load questions from that site).

### Embed

Because it's rendered by the browser, you can include it in your website/blog/etc in an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://crashthatch.com/stacktunnel/"></iframe>
```

### Download

No Download / Plugin required. Just a recent version of Chrome or Firefox.

### Code

The code is purely JavaScript, with no server side code at all. Feel free to inspect / view / modify / use / comment.

[Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) is used for the rendering. [Threex.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex) is used for the mouse / interactivity helpers.
Rendering of the "HUD" question-detail are handled by [StackTack](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere).

License: MIT.

### Contact

[@ThomasFletcher](https://twitter.com/thomasfletcher) on Twitter or [Crashthatch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528263/crashthatch) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 I love this idea! **Really** cool. If you post a screenshot URL in a comment below, I will add it to the question for you.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. It gave me enough rep to add the screenshots myself. Thanks for the offer though.

Comment: It still works and looks cool.  But I am not sure whether it will be useful to me.