# StackTack WordPress Plugin - Embed Stack Exchange Questions in Your Blog.

Tags: app, wordpress, stacktack

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Have you ever asked a question or posted an answer to a question on a Stack Exchange site and said to yourself "I sure would like to share this on my blog?" Well, you could just post a link to the question on your blog - or you could use StackTack and really show some style.

This plugin is based on [a modified version of StackTack](https://stackapps.com/q/3244) and adds a button to the post editing toolbar. Simply click the button and paste the link to the question. That's it - the plugin takes care of the rest!

You can see a demo of the plugin [here](http://2buntu.com/995/how-to-tell-the-difference-between-unity-3d-and-unity-2d-via-au/).

#### License

StackTack WordPress Plugin is released under the [GNU General Public License (GPL) 2](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/GPL-2.0).

#### Download

You can download the plugin here:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stacktack

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

This plugin is written in PHP and JavaScript.

The code can be retrieved from here:
https://github.com/nathan-osman/StackTack

Comment: The link to the demo of the plugin is coming up 404.

Comment: @NathanOsman The demo link appears to be broken again:  "You can see a demo of the plugin here."