# StackTack - George Edison Remix (now with a few extra features!)

Tags: app, javascript, blog, stacktack

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

StackTack was originally listed [here](https://stackapps.com/q/518) on Stack Apps. The idea was terrific and [Soviut](https://stackapps.com/users/825/soviut) did such an awesome job building the application that I decided to fork it. My original intention was to make a few minimal tweaks here and there but it ended up being quite a bit different from the original. Here are some of the changes I have made:

- The icons and images in the sprite were removed (some of the effects - like the soft shadow - could be partially implemented in CSS).
- A build system for minifying the CSS and JS (plus a few other things) was added.
- Options can be specified globally yet overridden on a per-invocation and per-element basis. Options are now specified using HTML5 `data-*` attributes.
- API requests to the same site are grouped to cut down on requests.

Detailed instructions for adding StackTack to your blog / site are provided on the GitHub page (see below).

Also, if you have a WordPress blog, you can simply install [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/3237/stacktack-wordpress-plugin-embed-stack-exchange-questions-in-your-blog) plugin to add StackTack to your blog.

#### License

StackTack is released under the [BSD License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php).

#### Download

You will (unfortunately at this point) have to build StackTack from source using the instructions in the GitHub repository (see below).

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

StackTack is written in JavaScript and uses [Juice Builder](https://github.com/nathan-osman/Juice-Builder).

The code can be retrieved from here:
https://github.com/nathan-osman/StackTack