# QuestionPacker - Packs Question in a Webpage

Tags: app, questions, javascript, answers

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

It is my version of [StackTack](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere), which seems to be discontinued.

#### License

Inbox Reader is released under the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0).

#### Download

You can get QuestionPacker here:
http://teamfreehugs.github.io/stackexchange/questionpacker/clean.html

#### Contact

I can be reached at `eyeballcode@gmail.com`.

#### Code

QuestionPacker is written in html, javascript.
The code can be retrieved from here: 
https://github.com/TeamFreeHugs/teamfreehugs.github.io/blob/master/stackexchange/questionpacker/clean.html

#### Note

You can put this in an `<iframe>`.

Break your eyes [here](http://teamfreehugs.github.io/stackexchange/questionpacker/clean.html?question=6497&site=stackapps)

Comment: Is this still active?